# Blocked urls by Google

Tags: google, google-search-console

I have a website which is 2 years old now. I saw it after a long time now and was shocked to see that Google robot has blocked 104 pages of my website. I saw this through webmaster tools. IS there any way I can unblock them?
EDIT:
I have attached the image but can't provide the name of the website. Thanks
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say blocked what exactly do you mean? This part of webmaster tools usually lists urls YOU have blocked via robots.txt. Please post your website url and a screen shot of webmaster tools so we can help you better.

Comment: i am having the same problem , i have working from 1 year on my blog and when i check in google webmaster i am having 52 blocked ulr ... it just schoked me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your robots.txt file is blocking the search directory which Google seems to be finding 104 pages in. If you want those pages crawled and indexed you need to remove that line from your robots.txt file.

Comment: Which line is to be removed? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Remove: `Disallow: /search`

Comment: I don't think you can update the robots.txt on Blogspot, I think the search pages are blocked by default (remember that google own Blogspot)

Comment: You're probably best keeping the `/search` directory blocked. Google recommend you "Use robots.txt to prevent crawling of search results pages or other auto-generated pages", which is exactly what this does.